# Root Mean Square in Postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, machine-learning

I am working on Image Duplication Library which uses ML to predict image similarity. In this process  **Root Mean Square** is used to calculate the similarity between two images ( I'm not going into how). The function which does it looks like this.

```py
# Function that calulates the mean squared error (mse) between two image matrices
def _mse(imageA, imageB):
    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
    err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])
    return err
```

My model worked fine when I tested it on folders containing 5K images but it took way too much time. So I decided to refactor my code and store all tensors in a database. Why?

If I store the tensors of all images in a database than query upcoming image tensor with it I will get result quickly. Looping over all images again and again + matching one image **RMS** with others will result into many combinations which will take time.

**Solution**

If I store all tensors which are list or Array and store them in database like Postgres than I can easily query them with **RMS** w.r.t. to getting all images at once than looping over them and finding out duplicity.

I need your help to figure out if there is any way to query Postgres for getting images with closest **RMS**

*Something like this:*

```sql
SELECT ID_PARTNER, ID_ACCOUNT
  , SQRT(Avg( POWER(Act_F_1 - Pred_F_1 , 2) ) ) as feature_1_rmse
FROM ...
GROUP BY ID_PARTNER, ID_ACCOUNT
```

Similar Question: [Get RMSE score while fetching data from the Table directly.Write a query for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204822/get-rmse-score-while-fetching-data-from-the-table-directly-write-a-query-for-tha)

**This is what DataBase looks like**

[image: This is what database looks like]

Comment: I am confused about what you want to do. Where do the values Act_F_1 and Pred_F_1 come from and how often are they the same between queries?

Comment: Please visit: Get RMSE score while fetching data from the Table directly. Write a query for that link for checkout where Act_F_1 and Pred_F_1 came from..and I am trying to build an image duplication library..which can find duplicacy fast using DB directly in this case postgres.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you want to do correctly you just need to create a column to hold the RMSE calculation and then update the table to do the calculation.

```
UPDATE table_name as orig set RMSE=(select SQRT(Avg( POWER(Act_F_1 - Pred_F_1 , 2) ) ) from table_name as copy where orig.ID_PARTNER=copy.ID_PARTNER and orig.ID_ACCOUNT=copy.ID_ACCOUNT GROUP BY ID_PARTNER, ID_ACCOUNT);
```

edit: I hadn't noticed the group by. I think this creates a pre-calculated field correctly though it is likely very inefficient as I believe it will recalculate for each ID_PARTNER ID_ACCOUNT pair. There might be a better way to do this in SQL. I'd just `SELECT DISTINCT ID_PARTNER, ID_ACCOUNT from table_name` then run through that in code and `SELECT SQRT(Avg( POWER(Act_F_1 - Pred_F_1 , 2) ) ) from table_name where ID_PARTNER=? and ID_ACCOUNT=?` for each of tuples I have then `update table_name set RMSE=?` for each of those values. Alternatively you could have a table that's just ID_PARTNER, ID_ACCOUNT, RMSE and just put the results in there once.

Then the table in the database will have all the pre-computed values and you can run queries on it. If you want things close to a value of search_RMSE

```
SELECT ...,ABS(RMSE - search_RMSE) as RMSE_DIFF from table_name order by RMSE_DIFF;
```

That isn't necessarily a super optimised way to do the calcs. You talk about duplicity which would mean you're looking for identical values but your calcs are floating point so you could even end up with values that *should* be identical but don't end up that way. Do you only care about the closest value or do you care about a number of the closest values? If you just make a giant table and sort it by RMSE the closest value for each row will be the row above it or the row below and the collection of closest values will be just growing up and down from the row.

I'm not entirely sure why you want to involve a database in this unless you can't fit all the data in memory. If that is the case you could just put the raw data in the database and then use the select you reference with an order by clause and store that in chunks outside the db if you want.

Anyway lots of ways to do this, myself I'd just use a cython module to avoid the extremely slow math in python (it's notably faster than numpy and is almost identical to python,) and do all of this with in memory data structures and maybe some temporary files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer..but problem is that...I have huge collection of images which will increase with time...that's why I cant use cache memory like redis etc...and when it comes to storing RMS than there is problem again...because I have to RMS calculation with all previous. Images in db..now I cant put raw data because than I have to fetch all of it and make loop on it..which will be slow again :(

Comment: how many records do you have and what exactly do the data fields look like ie what data type? If you can calculate all the values and sort by them (which you could use a database to do and have it automatically handle memory and storage for you) then you can quickly find similar RMSE values. If you don't precalculate all of them and sort then you have to recalculate every search. If you get new records you can use an insertion sort. You could still use a database for this with clever fields. I am not suggesting something like REDIS I'm suggesting a table of data in RAM.

Comment: oh and does the idea of searching for images whose RMSE is within a certain margin of error work for you or do you need to be able to find say the x number of closest images?
A lot of my discussion depends on the query optimiser of PostGres and might be moot if you make an index on the RMSE value and your query requirements aren't an issue. Of course if your library is something someone runs locally and not say a web service where people put it through constant demand I think your problem is easily solved without a database or similar tool.

Comment: First, i have more than 1 Core image..now if the user uploads the 'x' image then i use CNN which generates a matrix then I have to match that matrix..nowhere sorting or any other search algorithm just fails.

Comment: But the RMSE values don't change for the existing images do they? Your question is about matching RMSE values against other RMSE values to find close values. If you add new images you can do an insertion sort and having a sorted list means you can quickly find close values. If the values for existing images change then you have to recalculate the entire table no matter what you do. All the db does for you is handle memory considerations and you do the trivial calculation in the DB engine instead of in python. This will be a speed boost cython would be faster still. Not sure it's enough.

Comment: my question is about Calculating RMS values on the fly when DB finds the query is running..and in the database, I have a matrix of images,s not RMS values...and RMS is the difference between two values..which is too costly to store in database...

Comment: You give an example of calculating it on the fly in your question though and say you want to do this for performance. The math I see also seems to indicate that you can pre-calculate the value and then just calculate the difference when you run a query (which is what I show in this answer).

Comment: Oh I see I missed the group by clause. Even though it means that you only have one value for each unique pair of ID_Partner and ID_ACCOUNT values and those values only change if new ID_Partner ID_ACCOUNT pairs are created so you should still be able to pre-calculate, update some values on insertions and use the table of values to find similar values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242679/discussion-between-david-oldford-and-nitesh-yadav).